# How transactions handled in spring boot based microservices,

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-transactions

For example, User ordered something on order service

Request handled by order service then to -> payment service with the order id and payment details and payment service complete the transaction by accepting payments.

in this case how a transaction can be handled
Happy Path: 
1. In the synchronous way how a transaction can be handled
2. In asynchronous if request handed over to the message broker how will this transaction handled, also how latency can be handled

In failure case
1. In a synchronous way  -- If Payment service unavailable or throwing some error  then how a transaction can be handled
2. In asynchronous if the request handed over to the message broker, and if the consumer(payment service) is down then how will the transaction handled
in both failure scenarios what message shall be displayed to Client

Comment: Well with rabbit mq its an event driven architecture ,one microservice emits the event and the relevant subscribers listen to it in case of failure also a event is emitted ,which is listened by subscribers .Rabbit mq provides a central point to distribute the request accordingly .The plus point is you can have a failure request from one microservice and success from one like your order was placed ,but payment cancelled (handled by two different microservices).